# How to display the options selected in previous steps of smart wizard

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, smart-wizard

I am working on a user interface for my project. I am using the Smart Wizard available at http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard

I am using the **smartwizard-modal.html** in the examples directory of smartwizard.

The smart wizard modal has 4 steps.

I added 4 multi select checkboxes in step-1 and step-2.

Let's say a user selects few options in step-1 and few options in step-2, how do I display these selected options in step-3 once the user clicks Next button in step-2 ?

Comment: You can use `localStorage` for this. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

in each of steps you can access to input in other steps, in smartWizard you should use event **showStep(stepNo)** and in its function get the values of checkboxex and use this value to a wanted input or text field

Comment: Thanks Alireza. I will check and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used simple JS functions to display the options in Step-3